# update onOptionsItemSelected() without setting a new a listener

Tags: java, android, toolbar

So I have a couple of settings fragments, and I want to do diffrent things when the 'save' icon is pressed, I can do this with `toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener`, but that would imply setting another listener for every other fragment, and that doesn't feel right, what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, try the following:

In your fragments, override the method `onOptionsItemSelected()`. If you've correctly assigned the options menu save button an item id, you may write the following code to achieve what you want.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.save_button: // Be sure to replace this id with yours!
            // <This is where you should put the code for the button's action>
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: The result would be the same, I would have to override it in every fragment

Comment: Yes that is the case. An alternative, if your fragments all have the same foundational function, is to create a fragment base class from which all of your fragments extend. In this base fragment you could override this method and it would be handled for all fragments that inherit the base.

Thus, individual fragments should only check option menu items unique to themselves. The base fragment will handle all cases of the save button being pressed. Make use of calling `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` to allow the action to cascade back toward the parent classes.